# Understanding the Data.Aeson FromJSON typeclass

Tags: json, haskell, yaml, ghc

I recently started using Data.Aeson for one of my projects. And I am recently new to Haskell as well. So I am trying to figure out how the implementation of `parseJSON` function in `FromJSON` typeclass works.

So I have a code from my codebase.

```
data MyProfile = MyProfile { name :: String, age :: Int } deriving Show

instance FromJSON MyProfile where
parseJSON (Object m) = MyProfile <$>
                       m .: "name" <*>
                       m .: "age"
parseJSON x          = fail ("not an object: " ++ show x)
```

And the YAML file I am trying to read is pretty simple as well.

```
profile:
    name: "Foo"
    age: 16
```

I am trying to understand the working of that applicative functor. I browsed through the Data.Aeson module and found that (.:) returns a Parser (FromJSON a).

So the facts that I have understood is,

- Object m holds the `profile:` section of the yaml
- `MyProfile` corresponds to `profile`
- `name` in `ParseJSON` is trying to get the value for the key in the JSON object m
- Similar with `age` as well
- And each `<*>` returns a `Parser (FromJSON)` which is then applied over to the next `<*>`

What I am not understanding is,

- How does `MyProfile` gets mapped to the `profile` section? What if I have a huge yaml file and multiple data defined in my program?
- In the code `MyProfile <$> m .: "name"`, shouldn't the first argument of `<$>` be a function? I perceive that `<$>` is similar to fmap and hence the first argument must be a function (which is applied to the second argument). But MyProfile is a data! Confusing!
- How is the yaml values, in this case, Foo and 16, added to the MyProfile data?

Please correct me if any of my understandings is wrong.

Comment: `<$>` _is_ `fmap`, it isn't just similar to.  And `MyProfile` in an expression is a constructor, which has the type `String -> Int -> MyProfile`.  When you see `MyProfile` in a type signature it's indicating the name of the data type.  Constructors are essentially just functions.

Comment: @bheklilr: Yeah that clears some part of my doubts. So in this case, `m .: "name"` returns a Parser ( FromJSON) and MyProfile is a FromJSON? So the function MyProfile is being applied over throughout the applicative functors? Is my understanding correct?